# What is the name of google chrome rss plugin?

Tags: javascript, rss, google-chrome

I want to detect if the user has already installed google chrome rss plugin or not. I want to do this using javascript like this :

`if (navigator.plugins[rss_chrome_plugin _name]) {
    // do some stuff if it is installed
    }`

The problem is that I don't know the name of the plugin.Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"RSS Subscription Extension (by Google)"
ID: nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd